# Efficiently selecting every nth row without ROW_NUMBER

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table consisting of about 20 million rows, totalling approximately 2 GB. I need to select every nth row, leaving me with only a few hundred rows. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it without getting a timeout.

`ROW_NUMBER` is not available, and keeping track of the current row number with a variable (e.g. `@row`) causes a timeout. I presume this is because it is still iterating over every row, but I'm not too sure. There's no integer index for me to use either. A `DATETIME` field is used instead. This is an example query using `@row`:

```
SET @row = 0;
SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE (@row := @row + 1) % 1555200 = 0;
```

Is there anything else I haven't tried?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tricky one for sure. You could work out the minimum date and then use a datediff to get you the sequential values, but this probably isn't sargeable (as below). For me, it took 18 seconds on a table with 16 million rows, but your mileage may vary.

** EDIT ** I should also add that this was with a nonclustered index scan against an index which included the date column (pretty sure this is forced by the function around the date but perhaps someone with more knowledge can expand on this). After creating an index against that column, I got 12 seconds.

Try it out and let me know how it goes :)

```
DECLARE @n INT = 5;

SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, first_date.min_date, DATE_COLUMN) AS ROWNUM
FROM 
    ss.YOUR_TABLE
OUTER APPLY 
(   SELECT 
        MIN(a.DATE_COLUMN) min_date
    FROM ss.YOUR_TABLE a
) first_date
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, first_date.min_date, DATE_COLUMN) % @n = 0
```

Edit again:

Just noticed this has been accepted as an answer... In case anyone else comes across this, it probably shouldn't be. On review, this only works if your datetime field has one entry per day and the datetime is sequential (in that rows are added in the same order as the datetime, or if the datetime is the primary key).

Again only works per day with the above caveats, you can change the date diff to use any unit (Month, Year, Minute etc) if you have one row added per unit of time.